# WebRTC: ICE failed since Firefox v 53

Tags: webrtc

I got a problem with my webRTC-project. My code works well at Chrome and Firefox until version 52. Since Firefox 53 i got the error: "ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details". This is my code:

```
let connection;
let dataChannel;

 const initCon = (initiatorBoolean, choosenONE) => {
     createConnection();
     startConnection(initiatorBoolean, choosenONE);
     console.log('initCon(' + initiatorBoolean + ') / choosenONE = ' +choosenONE);
 }
var boolJoin =  false;
var lobbies = [];
var me = prompt("Please enter your name", "Bert");


// Helper für das Errorlogging
const logErrors = err => console.log(err);

// Websockets-Verbindung herstellen
const socket = io.connect('http://7daysclub.de:8080');

/* Methode to send information between to Users
*@param
*receiver= User who get the message
*type= Type of the message: could be init, joined, getUsers, setUsers, offer, answer, candidate
*descr= Content of the message
*/
 const sendMessage = (receiver, type, descr) => {
   message = Object.assign({to: 'default'}, {
       user: receiver,
       type: type,
       descr: descr,
       from: me
   });
   socket.emit('message', message);
   console.log("send: " + message.type + ". to: " + message.user);
};

const createConnection = () => {
    //Verbindung erstellen
    connection = new RTCPeerConnection( {
    'iceServers': [
        {

          /*
          'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
          */
          'urls': 'stun:185.223.29.90:3478'


        },
        {

          'urls': 'turn:185.223.29.90:3478',
          'credential': '***',
          'username': '***'


        }
    ]
    });
    connection.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(event) {
      console.log('state: '+connection.iceConnectionState );
      if (connection.iceConnectionState === "failed" ||
          connection.iceConnectionState === "disconnected" ||
          connection.iceConnectionState === "closed") {
        // Handle the failure
      }
    };

}

const call = choosenONE => {

    if (!boolJoin) {
        sendMessage(choosenONE, 'joined', null);
    }

};

// Nachricht vom Signaling-Kanal empfangen
const receiveMessage = message => {
   console.log("receive: " + message.type);

   //Filter messages
   if (message.user != 'all' && message.user != me) {
       console.log("Block= " + message.user);
       return;
   }
   // Nachricht verarbeiten
   switch (message.type) {

       // Partner ist verfügbar
      case 'joined':
         choosenONE = message.from;
         sendMessage( choosenONE, 'init', null);
         boolJoin = true;
         initCon(true, choosenONE);
         break;

      case 'getUsers':
         sendMessage(message.from,'setUsers', null)
         lobbies.push(message.from);
         lobbylist();
         console.log('add User: ' + lobbies[lobbies.length-1] + ' to List');
         break;

      case 'setUsers':
         lobbies.push(message.from);
         console.log('add User: ' + lobbies[lobbies.length-1] + ' to List');
         lobbylist();
         break;

      // Verbindungsaufbau wurde vom Partner angefordert
      case 'init':
         choosenONE = message.from;
         boolJoin = true;
         initCon(false, choosenONE);
         break;


      // Ein SDP-Verbindungsangebot ist eingegangen – wir erstellen eine Antwort
      case 'offer':
        connection
          .setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.descr))
          .then(() => connection.createAnswer())
          .then(answer => connection.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer)))
          .then(() => sendMessage(message.from,'answer', connection.localDescription, me))
          .catch(logErrors);
         break;

      // Eine SDP-Verbindungsantwort auf unsere Anfrage ist eingegangen.
      case 'answer':
         connection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.descr));
         break;

      // Der Partner hat eine mögliche Host-Port-Kombination ("ICE Candidate") gefunden
      case 'candidate':
         connection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate({candidate: message.descr}));
         break;
   }
};

socket.on('message', receiveMessage);



// Verbindung initialisieren
const startConnection = (isCreator, choosenONE) => {
    // Wenn wir mögliche Kommunikationsendpunkte finden, diese an den Partner weitergeben
    connection.onicecandidate = event => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            sendMessage(choosenONE, 'candidate', event.candidate.candidate);
        }
    };

    // Wenn die Gegenseite einen Stream hinzufügt, diesen an das video-element hängen
   connection.ontrack = (e) => {
      document.getElementById('vidRemote').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
   };

   // Falls wir der erste Teilnehmer sind, starten wir den Verbindungsaufbau
   if (isCreator) {
      // Datenkanal anlegen
      dataChannel = connection.createDataChannel('chat');
      onDataChannelCreated(dataChannel);

      connection
        .createOffer()
        .then(offer => connection.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer)))
        .then(() => sendMessage(choosenONE, 'offer', connection.localDescription))
        .catch(logErrors);

   } else {

      // Wenn wir nicht der Initiator sind, reagieren wir nur auf das Anlegen eines Datenkanals
      connection.ondatachannel = function (event) {
         dataChannel = event.channel;
         onDataChannelCreated(dataChannel);
      };

   }
};



const onDataChannelCreated = (channel, choosenONE) => {
   // Sobald der Datenkanal verfügbar ist, Chateingaben zulassen
   channel.onopen = () => {
      const enterChat = document.getElementById('enterChat');
      enterChat.disabled = false;
      enterChat.onkeyup = (keyevent) => {
         // Bei "Enter" absenden
         if (keyevent.keyCode === 13) {
            dataChannel.send(enterChat.value);
            appendChatMessage(me+':', enterChat.value);
            enterChat.value = '';
         }
      }
   };
   channel.onmessage = (message) => appendChatMessage(choosenONE+':', message.data);
};

const appendChatMessage = (name, text) => {
   const displayChat = document.getElementById('displayChat');
   const time = new Date().toString('H:i:s');
   displayChat.innerHTML = `<p>${name} - ${time}<br>${text}</p>` + displayChat.innerHTML;
};



function lobbylist() {
    allusers = "";
    lobbies.forEach( element => {
        allusers += "<li><button onclick=\"call('"+element+"')\">"+element+"</button></li>"
    });
    document.getElementById('lobbylist').innerHTML = allusers;
}

//Alle User bei Ankunft erfragen
sendMessage('all','getUsers', null);
lobbylist();
```

And about:webrtc =

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice' (registry) succeeded: ice

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref' (registry) succeeded: ice.pref

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type' (registry) succeeded: ice.pref.type

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.srv_rflx' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x64

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.peer_rflx' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x6e

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.host' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x7e

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.relayed' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x05

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.srv_rflx_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x63

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.peer_rflx_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x6d

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.host_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x7d

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.relayed_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x00

(registry/INFO) insert 'stun' (registry) succeeded: stun

(registry/INFO) insert 'stun.client' (registry) succeeded: stun.client

(registry/INFO) insert 'stun.client.maximum_transmits' (UINT4) succeeded: 7

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.trickle_grace_period' (UINT4) succeeded: 5000

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.tcp' (registry) succeeded: ice.tcp

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.tcp.so_sock_count' (INT4) succeeded: 0

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.tcp.listen_backlog' (INT4) succeeded: 10

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.tcp.disable' (char) succeeded: \000

(generic/EMERG) Exit UDP socket connected

(generic/ERR) UDP socket error:Internal error at z:/build/build/src/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:283 this=00000000120CC400

(ice/INFO) z:/build/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)

(ice/INFO) z:/build/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)

(ice/WARNING) z:/build/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) no streams with non-empty check lists

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) no streams with pre-answer requests

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) no checks to start

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP4:192.168.0.4:62417/TCP) active

(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0x802b

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)): Received response; processing

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate srflx(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)): Exceeded the number of retries

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)): mode 20, nr_turn_client_error_cb

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)) failed

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)): cancelling

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)): nr_turn_allocated_cb called with state 4

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:54605/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)): nr_turn_allocated_cb failed

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default)/STREAM(0-1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1512241952789000 (id=19327352835 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

(generic/EMERG) Exit UDP socket connected

(generic/ERR) UDP socket error:Internal error at z:/build/build/src/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:283 this=000000000BAE3000

(ice/INFO) z:/build/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)

(ice/INFO) z:/build/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)

(ice/WARNING) z:/build/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) no streams with non-empty check lists

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) no streams with pre-answer requests

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) no checks to start

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP4:192.168.0.4:63286/UDP)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP4:192.168.0.4:54433/TCP) active

(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0x802b

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:192.168.0.4:63286/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)): Received response; processing

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate srflx(IP4:192.168.0.4:63286/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:63286/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:63286/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:63286/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)::TURN): Received response; processing

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:63286/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:3478/UDP)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:185.223.29.90:50497/UDP lifetime=3600

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:192.168.0.4:63286/UDP|IP4:185.223.29.90:50497/UDP)

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/)): peer (PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default)/STREAM(0-1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1512242125375000 (id=19327352836 url=http://7daysclub.de/webrtc2/):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

+++++++ END ++++++++

And my turnserver config looks like this:

```
# TURN listener port for UDP and TCP (Default: 3478).
# Note: actually, TLS & DTLS sessions can connect to the 
# "plain" TCP & UDP port(s), too - if allowed by configuration.
#
listening-port=3478

# TURN listener port for TLS (Default: 5349).
# Note: actually, "plain" TCP & UDP sessions can connect to the TLS & DTLS
# port(s), too - if allowed by configuration. The TURN server 
# "automatically" recognizes the type of traffic. Actually, two listening
# endpoints (the "plain" one and the "tls" one) are equivalent in terms of
# functionality; but we keep both endpoints to satisfy the RFC 5766 specs.
# For secure TCP connections, we currently support SSL version 3 and 
# TLS version 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. SSL2 "encapculation mode" is also supported.
# For secure UDP connections, we support DTLS version 1.
#
tls-listening-port=5349

# Listener IP address of relay server. Multiple listeners can be specified.
# If no IP(s) specified in the config file or in the command line options, 
# then all IPv4 and IPv6 system IPs will be used for listening.
#
listening-ip=185.223.29.90

# Relay address (the local IP address that will be used to relay the 
# packets to the peer).
# Multiple relay addresses may be used.
# The same IP(s) can be used as both listening IP(s) and relay IP(s).
#
# If no relay IP(s) specified, then the turnserver will apply the default
# policy: it will decide itself which relay addresses to be used, and it 
# will always be using the client socket IP address as the relay IP address
# of the TURN session (if the requested relay address family is the same
# as the family of the client socket).
#
relay-ip=185.223.29.90


lt-cred-mech


# Realm for long-term credentials mechanism and for TURN REST API.
#
realm=7daysclub.de


#Local system IP address to be used for CLI server endpoint. Default value
# is 127.0.0.1.
#
cli-ip=185.223.29.90

# CLI server port. Default is 5766.
#
cli-port=5766
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at your online demo there is no a=candidate line in the remote SDP which suggests the candidate is never added.

`sendMessage(choosenONE, 'candidate', event.candidate.candidate);`

this is discarding the sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex which needs to be signalled to the remote peer. Add a .catch to your addIceCandidate to log any errors.

Comment: Dude you are my official hero for the next 20 years! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This was also the problem I was having just now, due to sdpMLineIndex being missed in the google codelab I was building on top of. Any idea why FF fails sometimes when sdpMLineIndex is not set and Chrome doesn't fail?
I've also noticed that usually FF comes up with more candidates (I'm testing over LAN)

Comment: sounds like you are running into https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1456417
Can you file an issue on the codelab please?